# Wordpress Storefront theme; flexible q-ty of products depending on a screen resolution

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, storefront

I have a site run on  Wordpress + WooCommece + Storefront theme.
By default Storefront theme shows 4 product in a row… it is possible to increase/decrease number of products statically.
Is there are any way to make product q-ty in a row to be flexible depending on screen resolution? Let’s say 5-6 products in row for FHD+, 4 products for regular resolutions like 1280×768(800) e.t.c.
My logic is that q-ty of products should be managed locally by browser… therefore we came to CSS… something like…

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px;) and (max-width 1079) 
/*some code to show 4 products in a row */
@media screen and (min-width: 1080px) 
/*some code to show 5-6 products in a row */
```

The only question is… what code it might be?  (sorry I’m newby in WordPress/WooCommerce/WeB sites in general  )
My guess is that code should be different for Shop page and WooCommerce blocks added to ANY page.
Can someone goive some hints of how to manage product q-ty in a row?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!! Without seeing any of the HTML markup there is no way we can help you. Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @disinfor I thought t might be a bit too much to post here the ALL Wordpress theme HTML markup here. Let me just post a link to the site https://prettify.ru (I'm not adwertising )

Comment: You don't have to post all the HTML. Just the section you are trying to style with the CSS. External links will not work, since once you fix the issue, that will become invalid.